# Excel XML remove Namespaces

Tags: excel, xml

I have the current problem, that everytime I want to export data from an excel to XML I have namespaces like ns1 and ns2.
When I start mapping the XML, the namespaces already appear and when i export it, they are still there and change some of the values from my xml source, so i need to change a a lot manually after the export.

Does anyone know, how to avoid those namespaces?

Here you can see what I mean (sorry for blacking out):

[image]

I could only remove the namespace afterwards, but I would like not to do it manually.

Thanks

Comment: You can use XSLT to remove namespaces from the XML file.

Comment: yeah i can remove it afterwards, but i dont want to create it with namespaces.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky: True, but that's not what OP really needs to hear here -- that's a tactical answer [where a strategic answer is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75866959/290085).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to configure Excel to generate XML component names without namespaces.  XML namespaces are an important part of the identity of XML components (elements and attributes).  Standards are written, including for [Excel's XML](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/), that specify the names and compositions of the components of an XML document.  You should not be trying to eliminate this important, standard part of XML component names.

Take the time to learn how to work with XML namespaces — it's not that hard.  Moreover, your work will be more robust; your data, more interoperable.

Comment: Okay, but the system I am generating the XML File for, does not accept a file with namespaces, so I do need to remove them.

Comment: Then either (1) you misunderstand the system you're generating the XML for, or (2) the system you're generating the XML for is critically flawed and should be fixed or replaced, not catered to by perpetuating its problem.